# C++ Function Issue

Tags: c++

A while ago I was given the task of converting a Java program to C++.

I've done this, and I've started encountering some odd errors that don't seem to make any sense to me.

The program consists of three files. A main.ccp, a date.ccp and a date.h.

**main.ccp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "Date.h"

using namespace ::std;

string weekday(Date date);

int main() {

    int day, month, year;

    cout << "What date (d m y)? ";

    cin >> day >> month >> year;

    Date event = Date(day, month, year);
    cout << ("That was a " + weekday(event));
    return 0;
}

string weekday(Date date) {
    const string days[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    Date trial = Date(1, 1, 1);
    int weekday = 6;

    if (Date::precedes(trial)) {
        return "Mysteryday";
    } else {
        while (trial.precedes(date)) {
            trial.advance();
            weekday = (weekday + 1) % 7;
        }
        return days[weekday];
    }
}
```

**Date.ccp**

```
#include "Date.h"

Date::Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        day_ = day;
        month_ = month;
        year_ = year;
    }

    int Date::getDay () {
        return day_;
    }

    void Date::setDay (int day) {
        day_ = day;
    }

    int Date::getMonth () {
        return month_;
    }

    void Date::setMonth (int month) {
        month_ = month;
    }

    int Date::getYear () {
        return year_;
    }

    void Date::setYear (int year) {
        year_ = year;
    }

    bool Date::isLeapYear () {

        bool lear = false;

        if (this->year_ <= 1752) {
            if (this->year_ % 4 == 0) {
                lear = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            lear = false;
        }
        if (this->year_ > 1752) {
            if (this->year_ % 4 == 0 && this->year_ % 100 != 0) {
                lear = true;
            }
            else if (this->year_ % 4 == 0 && this->year_ % 100 == 0 && this->year_ % 400 == 0) {
                lear = true;
            }
            else {
                lear = false;
            }
        }
        return lear;
    }

    int Date::daysInMonth () {
        // "30 days hath September ... "
        switch (this->month_) {
        case 9 :
        case 4 :
        case 6 :
        case 11 :
            return 30;
        default :
            return 31;
        case 2 :
            return this->isLeapYear() ? 29 : 28;
        }
    }

    void Date::advance () {
        this->day_;

        if (this->day_ == 3 && this->month_ == 9 && this->year_ == 1752) {
            day_ = 14;
            month_ = 9;
            year_ = 1752;
        }

        if (this->day_ > this->daysInMonth()) {
            this->day_ = 1;
            this->month_++;
        }
        if (this->month_ > 12) {
            this->month_ = 1;
            this->year_++;

        }
    }

   bool Date::precedes (Date date) {
        return this->year_ < date->year_
            || this->year_ == date->year_ && this->month_ < date->month_
            || this->year_ == date->year_ && this->month_ == date->month_ && this->day_ < date->day_;
    }
```

**Date.h**

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date {
public:
    Date (int day, int month, int year);
    int getDay();
    void setDay();
    int getMonth();
    void setMonth();
    int getYear();
    void setYear();
    bool isLeapYear();
    int daysInMonth();
    void advance();
    bool precedes(Date date);

private:
        int day_;
        int month_;
        int year_;
};

#endif  /* DATE_H */
```

I seem to be getting lots of the same errors when I compile.

Date.cpp:97:95: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Date’

I'm not sure if I've done the declaration right or not.

Comment: You may want to consider making `year_`, `day_`, and `month_` into a single `int[3]`, so that you can use things like `lexicographical_compare` against them.

Comment: @Andrew - Removing the errors from the question without making a note of that is not nice. It is really confusing for those of us that come here later.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put semicolons after your class's closing `}`.

Comment: Oh wow, I can hardly believe that. Haha, that fixed most of the errors. Thankyou. Oh how careless of me.

Answer (score 0):

The class definition for `Date` is not terminated with a semicolon. Because you `#include`d this file in main.cpp, the first statement after the header is the one that won't parse due to this syntax error; thus you get the error in the wrong place.

Comment: I still seem to be getting an error when I call the function Date.precedes.

main.cpp:31:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘Date::precedes(Date&)’
Date.h:16:10: note: candidate is: bool Date::precedes()

Comment: @AndrewBooth: Okay, that's a different error though. You've declared `precedes` as taking no parameters: `bool precedes();`.

Comment: How do I give it the declaration to use input from main?

Comment: @Andrew: Declare it as taking parameters. (Just like you'd declare any other function that takes parameters) (e.g. your `string weekday(Date date);`)

Comment: It seems to take paramaters under the Date.ccp, do I also need to declare this under it's prototype definition in Date.h?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes. Being a member function doesn't change any of the requirements of being a function. One of those is that parameters have to match. (Why would you expect otherwise? Type checking is kind of the point of prototyping a function in the first place!)